# mapping certain values from one worksheet to another using loop and array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to map certain values from a data list to another worksheet if certain conditions are met. I have done this in the past using arrays but now I am getting a runtime error and I can't debug. The mapping works like this (assuming condition is met): column A to A, B to B, AK to C, AL to D and AM to E.

```
Sub newcontracts()
    Dim source As Variant
    Dim destination As Variant
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Long

    source = Array("A", "B", "AK", "AL", "AM")
    desitnation = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

    LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Contracts").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Worksheets("New Contracts").Range("A2:i10").ClearContents

    With Worksheets(2)
        For x = 11312 To LastRow
            If (IsEmpty(Cells(x, 39)) = False Or Cells(x, 39) <> 0) And Cells(x, 40) = "no" Then
                For j = 0 To 4
                    .Range(source(j) & x).Copy Sheets("New Contracts").Range(destination(j) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1)
                Next j
            End If
        Next x
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks a million!

Comment: "*I am getting a runtime error and I can't debug.*" (1) What error? (2) Where (which code line)? (3) In `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` you need to specify the sheet for `Rows.Count` too, like `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` otherwise it assumes ActiveSheet which fails either for this line or for the following line where you have the same issue. **Every** `Rows` needs a specific sheet specified (there are a few in your code!)  same for **all** `Cells`.

Comment: (4) [**Always** use `Long` instead of `Integer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613) Excel has more rows than Integer can handle!

Comment: Also notice that `Sheets(2)` may not be the same worksheet as `Worksheets(2)` nor the same as `Sheets2`. The `Sheets` collection additionally contains charts not only workbooks. So make sure which one to use. Most times people really meant to use `Worksheets` if they write `Sheets`. Make sure you know that difference! Using both mixed up will make you run into issues if you use eg. charts.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the new iteration of the code that seems to  be working. @Peh, i'm not sure I have to specify every sheet. As I declare what sheet before but your points are noted. Anyway...here is the code...I will try Ralphs version soon...thanks again everyone for your input

```
Sub newcontracts()

Dim source As Variant
Dim destination As Variant
Dim j As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRow3 As Long

source = Array("A", "B", "AK", "AL", "AM")
destination = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")


LastRow3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Contracts").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("New Contracts").Range("A2:i10").ClearContents

With Worksheets(2)

LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 25 To LastRow

If .Rows(x).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then

If (IsEmpty(.Cells(x, 39)) = False Or .Cells(x, 39) <> 0) And .Cells(x, 40) = "no" Then
  For j = 0 To 4
.Range(source(j) & x).Copy Sheets("New Contracts").Range(destination(j) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
Next j
End If
End If
Next x




End With

End Sub
```